# firebase grab by orderByChild then update results key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i have this query and currently collects all the data with `materialName` equals to gold. I wanted change all to false.

```
// materialName = "gold" for example
database.ref('/app/posts').orderByChild('material').startAt(materialName).endAt(materialName).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    const materials = snapshot.val();
})
```

I have tried something like this:

```
database.ref('/app/posts').orderByChild('material').startAt(materialName).endAt(materialName).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    database.ref('/app/posts').update({material: false});
})
```

also I have tried this:

```
const newData = Object.assign({}, materials, {material: false});
// but this updates outside of the post, result will be:


"posts" : {
      "material": false,
      "post-1503586" : {
        "title": "sample title",
        "material" : "gold"
      },
      "post-9172991" : {
        "title": "sample title",
        "material" : "silver"
      }
    }
```

sample json:

```
"posts" : {
      "post-1503586" : {
        "title": "sample title",
        "material" : "gold"
      },
      "post-9172991" : {
        "title": "sample title",
        "material" : "silver"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop over the results (since there can be multiple matching nodes) and then update each:

```
database.ref('/app/posts')
  .orderByChild('material')
  .equalTo(materialName)
  .once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      child.ref.update({material: false});
    });
});
```

You'll also note that I changed your `.startAt().endAt()` to an `equalTo()`, which gives the same results with less code.